# Can't read from multiple fifos

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

I have a really annoying problem while trying to read from multiple fifos. I have 1 process that waits for structure from fifo and few processes that are sending him those structures on signal. After first read I can't read anything more.. from any signal. It looks like the program frozes.

The sending process has this in main with

```
myfifo = '/tmp/myfifo{0}' //{0} is a number that every process has individual.
mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, &demon1 , sizeof(demon1));
close(fd);
while (1)
{
}
```

and this in signal_handler

```
void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGUSR1)
    {
        //some declarations here
        mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
        write(fd, &demon1 , sizeof(demon1));
    }
}
```

While the reading process has

```
myfifo[i] = /tmp/myfifo{0} // {0} is i which is the number of process that sends.

 while(1)
 {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       fd = open(myfifo[i], O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
       r = read(fd, &demon1, sizeof(demon1));
       if(r > 1)
       {
           //printf struct elements
       }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Please send a minimal working example. Do you, for example, close each fd again after opening in the _reading process_? Otherwise you will soon run out of file descriptors

Comment: this by most part is everything other things are printing and setting directories.

Comment: I suggest reading the output of `man 7 fifo`, particularly the part about opening FIFOs in non-blocking mode. I think your write-only, non-blocking `open`s will fail with errno `ENXIO` when the other end of the FIFO is not open.

Answer (score 2):

You open the pipe inside the loop. That way, you quickly run out of file descriptors (which you would see if you checked the result of `open()` for errors).

I suggest to open all FIFOs outside the loop, store the file descriptors in an array and then just read each of them but ... the read will block. See `select(2)` to find out which FIFO has data.

Another solution would be a single FIFO and the writing process should send it's ID in the message. That way, the main process just has to listen to a single FIFO. If it wants to know who sent the message, it can look at the ID in the message. The problem here: You need some kind of locking or several processes will write to the FIFO at the same time and their data *can* get mixed up (this depends on the FIFO buffers).

Answer (score 1):

You do not close the filedescriptors after opening and reading:

```
while(1)
{
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       fd = open(myfifo[i], O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
       r = read(fd, &demon1, sizeof(demon1));
       if(r > 1)
       {
           //printf struct elements
       }
```

Here a `close(fd)` is missing.

```
    }
}
```

Since the open is non-blocking, the maximum number of fds per process is reached very soon and subsequent opens will fail.

Comment: This still doesn't help, If I wont sent to myfifo[0] other fifos won't be read

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, I do not understand this comment, can you please elaborate a bit more what happens?

Comment: myfifo[0] has path to first fifo if I wont read from it I won't check the next one. 
For example if i sent first to myfifo[2] (the 3rd path) it will wait untile the myfifo[0] and myfifo[1] are read.

Comment: @Thomas As far as I can see, the reason for this is out of the scope of the code snippets you provide. Or maybe you are misinterpreting what you see. I can only advise you, to provide a minimal example which can actually be compiled and tested.

Comment: I think i found a way around by deleting pipes.. although im not really happy with the result. Will se how it goes. I will provide mine answer later on.